# Modify rsyslog output when relaying

Tags: rsyslog

I am using a server with rsyslog to send logs to Loggly (action(type="omfwd" ) from a variety of network devices.

Unfortunately some devices are not showing up correctly - my switch with hostname switch1950a is seen as host "2019" on Loggly.  I want to add a few lines prior to forwarding to modify this hostname.

`syslog:
appName:switch1950a
facility:local use 7
host:2019
priority:187
severity:Error
timestamp:2019-05-21T10:39:36+02:00`

This is a new install.  I have ensured $Preservefqdn on is in the config.

Rsyslog config file:

`template(name="LogglyFormat" type="string"
string="<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% [XXXXXXX@4XXXX tag=\"RsyslogTLS\"] %msg%\n"
)
action(type="omfwd" protocol="tcp" target="logs-01.loggly.com" port="6514" template="LogglyFormat" StreamDriver="gtls" StreamDriverMode="1" StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/name" StreamDriverPermittedPeers="*.loggly.com")`

The received output should be

`syslog:
appName:switch1950a
facility:local use 7
host:switch1950a
priority:187
severity:Error
timestamp:2019-05-21T10:39:36+02:00`

Comment: Can't you just change the template above and replace `%HOSTNAME%` by `%app-name%` so it appears twice, since that seems to hold the right hostname?

Comment: Not sure that would work to fix this but it would probably ruin all the other logs, no?

Comment: I don't know anything about Loggly, so I'm just looking at the rsyslog part. You can always have 2 templates and choose an action by matching on some aspect of the input, such as `if $msg contains 'switch1950a' then { action(...,template="t1")}else{ action(...,template="t2")}`

Comment: Will give it a go. Is there no way to "overwrite" a host name so to speak?

Comment: You cannot change properties like hostname, as these are set when rsyslog parses the incoming packet. Perhaps`%fromhost%` might be correct. You can create your own variables, set them, use them in templates; see [variables](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/index.html).
The errant switch may be using a non-syslog format. There are many [modules](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/index.html) to parse packets. Also [liblognorm](https://github.com/rsyslog/liblognorm/blob/master/doc/configuration.rst) can be used to decode a packet.